# Lollipop: How to change underline color of AutoTextView?

Tags: android, textview

Below method is not working as i know `AutoTexview extends EditText`

```
autoTextview.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(AppUtil.getColor(mActivity, R.color.blue_color_with_no_opacity), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Below method is working fine

```
edittext.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(AppUtil.getColor(mActivity, R.color.blue_color_with_no_opacity), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

I am not able to identify why it's happening Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just change color Accent,

```
autoTextview.setTheme(R.style.myAutoTextViewStyle);
```

And Now define your style in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="myAutoTextViewStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="colorAccent">YOUR_HEX_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

Comment: its throwing an error. No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'accentColor'.

<style name="myAutoTextViewStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="accentColor">#454545</item>
    </style>

Comment: and there is no such method "autoTextView.setTheme()"

Comment: Sorry It's 'colorAccent' not 'accentColor'. I edited answer

Comment: Do you have appcompat library in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: yes i have
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'